# Creating an RDD[(ImmutableBytesWritable, Result)] in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, rdd

I'm working on a unit test where I need to create an `RDD[(ImmutableBytesWritable, Result)]`. The data only contain a unique `id` and a non-unique `value` columns.

I could create a DataFrame from a List using `toDF`, and transform it into `RDD[Row]`; but I'm having trouble mapping it to `RDD[(ImmutableBytesWritable, Result)]`.

```
val values = List((1, 1234), (2, 123), (3, 1234))
import spark.implicits._
val df = values.toDF("id", "value")
val counts : RDD[(ImmutableBytesWritable, Result)] = df.rdd.map(
  row => (new ImmutableBytesWritable(), Result.create(...))
)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the code that you have so far?

Comment: @Jeremy yes, good call.

Comment: What is Result?

Comment: @Jeremy it's `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use HBase but given the signature that you are trying to build I came up with this. Give it a try.

I created a Cell using CellUtil for building Result.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{Cell, CellUtil}

import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

import scala.math.BigInt

import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.rdd._
import org.apache.spark.sql._

import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable

object Practice extends App {

  val sparkConfig = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local[*]")
  val ss = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConfig).getOrCreate()
  val values = Seq((1, 1234), (2, 123), (3, 1234))

  import ss.implicits._

  val df = values.toDF("id", "value")
  val counts: RDD[(ImmutableBytesWritable, Result)] = df.rdd.map{ row =>
    val key = row.getAs[Int]("id")
    val keyByteArray = BigInt(key).toByteArray
    val ibw = new ImmutableBytesWritable()
    ibw.set(keyByteArray)

    val value = row.getAs[Int]("value")
    val valueByteArray = BigInt(value).toByteArray
    val cellList = List(CellUtil.createCell(valueByteArray))
    val cell: java.util.List[Cell] = ListBuffer(cellList: _*)
    val result = Result.create(cell)

    (ibw, result)

  }
}
```

Printing the results, which is not indicative of a good answer, gives you this:

```
KeyValue(03,keyvalues={\x04\xD2//LATEST_TIMESTAMP/Maximum/vlen=0/seqid=0})
KeyValue(01,keyvalues={\x04\xD2//LATEST_TIMESTAMP/Maximum/vlen=0/seqid=0})
KeyValue(02,keyvalues={{//LATEST_TIMESTAMP/Maximum/vlen=0/seqid=0})
```

Comment: Note that I converted from a Scala List to a java.util.List. You could probably skip that and just create a Java list to begin with.

Comment: Thanks! What are you trying to say with the printed results?

Comment: Nothing in particular. Just showing that the app runs. Since I don't have HBase I can't actually test the results. If you found my answer helpful please consider marking my answer as "Accepted".